# Is Halo's MJOLNIR armor related to Thor's hammer Mjölnir?

Tags: halo, mjolnir, armor

In the *[Halo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(series))* series the Master Chief (Spartan John-117) wears a suit of armor called the [MJOLNIR Powered Assault Armor](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir_Powered_Assault_Armor).

[image: Image of the "MJOLNIR Powered Assault Armor" from the Halo game series]

**I'm wondering whether this use of "MJOLNIR" has anything to do with the [Mjölnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mjolnir_(comics)) from Norse mythology or Thor?**

Comment: [Mjolnir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) was in Norse mythology way before he appeared in any Marvel comics or movies.

Comment: @RogueJedi Yeah but Thor visited Earth and started the Norse mythology, ha checkmate!

Comment: It should also be considered that Halo itself takes place on Earth (or partially so) and contains all of its history.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's likely named after [Thor's hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir) from Norse mythology. Nothing I can find implies it has any relation to the Marvel weapon specifically.

Halo has a history of similarly-named armor components.

For example:

- ["YGGDRASIL"](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/HRUNTING/YGGDRASIL_Mark_I_Prototype_Armor_Defense_System), [originally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yggdrasil) the world tree in Norse Mythology.
- ["GUNGNIR"](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir_Powered_Assault_Armor/(G)_variant), [originally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gungnir) the spear of Odin.
- ["Valkyrie"](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir_Powered_Assault_Armor/Valkyrie), [originally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valkyrie) the female warriors of Odin.

[Many](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Permutations) of the names of armor in the series appear to be inspired by mythology and history.

[image: Halo armor]

Comment: As another example, the maps Ragnarok and Valhalla stand out in particular.

Comment: The Spartans in Haloverse are raised on the history of various warriors. They're literally named after the ancient Spartans. Calling the armor Mjolnir acknowledges that the suit is a tool, a weapon in its own right.

Comment: @Broklynite: re "Spartan" Hah somehow I never even thought of that. Duh.

Comment: It makes a bit more sense if you read Fall of Reach.

Answer (score 3):

As I recall correctly it's "explained" in Fall of Reach. The similarity with Thor's hammer is that only "worthy" can use it. (as in Norse mythology depicted in various cartoons and Marvel universe)
When normal marine was test driving this armor he was crushed since his reflexes weren't fast enough.

Spartans came through whole augmentation process where their physical strength, brain processing power etc. were increased way over normal human capabilities and they had genetic predisposition to begin with.

Well that is until Spartan III-IV programs where they tried to make whole process less expensive. Therefore armor had to be adapted to be used by less augmented personnel.

Comment: "as in Norse mythology":  I don't believe this quality comes into the mythology, see [this, on Mythology.SE](http://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/108/was-the-mj%C3%B6lnir-usable-by-only-the-worthy).

Comment: thanks for this information, edited. It usually is depicted like this in cartoons and in marvel universe.

Comment: @RoughTomato: Norse Mythology and "cartoons"/"the Marvel universe" are not the same thing. You know that Thor/Norse mythology predates Marvel by hundreds of years, yeah?

Comment: I do realize that. Don't get the point of your comment though. Question was wether it was related to one depicted in Thor series, not "is it related to the original Norse mythology". As for the fact that it's often depicted differently. Well, that's not my fault. No need to be unpleasant about it.